# How can i remove popular tags just for product page?Magento

Tags: html, magento

I have this page:

[link](http://s1.busteco.ro/frontend/tibi/index.php/electronics/cell-phones/nokia-2610-phone.html)

At the bottom of the page is a section with **Popular Tags**.I want to remove this section xml code.

Where it is located?
Which is the name of the file and what section i should to remove?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you can simply add in your local xml to remove tag block

```
<catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="product.info.additional">
            <action method="unsetChild"><name>product_tag_list</name></action>
        </reference>
       <reference name="left">
         <remove name="tags_popular" />
       </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
```

Comment: yes but I do not find local.xml page ... and put in code in page.xml and there is not working. Somehow know where to find local.xml page?

Comment: What do you mean? I do not understand

Comment: You need to create a local.xml file in your theme layout folder :)